Time in GMT format became CST format after appending the time vector
I have a vecotr a, and a single element b. Just to append b at the end of a.
 a = [1] "2022-01-01 08:07:18 GMT" "2022-01-01 08:14:03 GMT" "2022-01-01 08:16:53 GMT" "2022-01-01 10:12:36 GMT" "2022-01-01 12:10:57 GMT" "2022-01-01 12:15:30 GMT"
 [7] "2022-01-01 14:53:12 GMT" "2022-01-01 17:06:42 GMT" "2022-01-01 17:18:24 GMT" "2022-01-01 19:14:30 GMT" "2022-01-01 21:00:57 GMT" "2022-01-01 21:21:27 GMT"
[13] "2022-01-01 21:55:45 GMT" "2022-01-01 22:20:30 GMT" "2022-01-01 22:29:51 GMT"

b = "2022-01-01 23:00:00 GMT"

x = c(a, b) # x equals to a with b appended after

However, the time format is changed, when print(x), the time in GMT is automatically converted into CST format.
[1] "2022-01-01 16:07:18 CST" "2022-01-01 16:14:03 CST" "2022-01-01 16:16:53 CST" "2022-01-01 18:12:36 CST" "2022-01-01 20:10:57 CST" "2022-01-01 20:15:30 CST"
 [7] "2022-01-01 22:53:12 CST" "2022-01-02 01:06:42 CST" "2022-01-02 01:18:24 CST" "2022-01-02 03:14:30 CST" "2022-01-02 05:00:57 CST" "2022-01-02 05:21:27 CST"
[13] "2022-01-02 05:55:45 CST" "2022-01-02 06:20:30 CST" "2022-01-02 06:29:51 CST" "2022-01-02 07:00:00 CST"

How to fix it?
Many thanks.

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309680/append-a-datetime-object-on-posixct
